# class (Object) vs id

Tags: javascript

During the web development i encountered with many problems and resolved it but these problems gave me a thought which i want to share and would like to know your view.

Which One is efficient `Class Or ID` : Both has own specification but i think Class is more convenient over ID (if you are dealing with thousands of IDs.)
I know Id is quite efficient for DOM Traversing but what if you have hundreds of elements with IDs, How do you manage ?

Using CLASS : One class can be derived by many elements and the individual elements can be dealt by using `"this" object`.

I am curious to know your view OR how do you handle the project/projects when you have many-many elements with ID or Class name

```
<div class="example" onclick="function click(this);"> </div>  
<div class="example" onclick="function click(this);"> </div> 
<div class="example" onclick="function click(this);"> </div>


    function click(obj){
        alert(obj.classname + "We can access any individual element by using Object");   
       }

<div id="exm_1"> </div> 
<div id="exm_2"> </div> 
<div id="exm_3"> </div> 

but in case of ID, we go through each ID
```

Comment: I don't really understand your example, but for me, classes and IDs have such a distinct purpose that there is no "either...or". ID: if you need to act on a single element. Class: if you have to act on multiple elements. It is like asking what is better, a variable with a single element or an array.

Comment: @Felix: but Class (this) Object can act as same as ID but id can only works with single element. so my point is to work with one Class instead of multiple id when you have many elements

Comment: @Bibhaw: That's my point. If you have several elements that should be treated the same, use a class. But you have no advantage if you use a class as ID.

Comment: @Felix: can't 'this' object acts as individual element?

Comment: @Bibhaw: I think you have a misunderstanding here. If you attach an event handler to an element, inside the handler, `this` will always refer to the element, no matter if it has a class or ID. You can add `onclick="function click(this);"` to your ID examples and it would be the same (obviously `obj.className` would be empty).

Comment: @Felix: Yes, you are right 'obj.className' would be empty in case of ID. But in my example i just tried to explain how Class works as individual element. Anyway thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I liked a few guidelines that are put together by one of my managers, I would like to mention them here:

Start with the following common sense guidelines, and apply them to both JavaScript selectors and CSS selectors.

Use an ID if:

- You are certain that the element only
  appears once in the whole page.
- The desired style or JS behavior is
  specific to only one area of the
  whole page.

Typical ID Examples:

- Large container divs for entire
  sections of the page ("#interior",
  "#global-status", "#tree-container")
- Links or buttons with special names
  and purposes ("#add-new-report",
  "#preview-popup")

Use a class if:

- It is possible for the element to
  appear multiple times in the same
  document.
- The desired style or JS
  behavior is general and is applicable
  to multiple elements.

Typical Class Examples:

- Reusable interface patterns
  (".action-links", ".title-bar",
  ".h1-with-border")
- Element states
  (".current-selected", ".highlighted")

Comment: Thanks mahesh, This is what i wanted to know.

Answer (score 3):

You should follow this general guidelines:

2) Use a class when you need many elements to share some common behaviour, or when there's currently only one element but you're not sure if there will be more with the same behaviour in the future.

1) Use an Id when an element needs *unique identification* and you're sure there will be only one with it (think in the future code changes). There should never, never be 2 or more elements with the same id.

Hope this helps. Cheers